# Fb.ui way to post in user's page, timeline etc

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using fb.ui to share information but apparently user cannot choose where they want to post their information ie their page or timeline like sharer.php has. I could pass the page_id but its not fixed.Different users have their different page_id and multiple pages too.

Any suggestions?

This is what I have right now.

```
   FB.ui(
 {
 method: 'feed',
 name : '" . $fb_title . "',
 link: '" . $url . "',
 picture     : '$image',
 description : '" . $fb_synopsis . "',
 message     : '" . $fb_synopsis . "'
```

},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed dialog is not meant to share to other profiles, it is only meant to share stuff on your own wall.

You either need to use sharer.php or take a look at the send dialog:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: The send dialog wouldn't suffice what I am looking for and sharer.php is deprecated and sometimes doesn't share the description and the images.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If sharer.php does not take the correct data, try putting the url in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ - it refreshes the data and shows warnings/errors too.